# How to align all desktop items Right side? by default it always have at left side?

Tags: windows-xp, desktop, icons, alignment

How to align all desktop items Right side? by default it always have at left side?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How to align all desktop items Right
>   side?

You can't, at least not automatically.

You can disable **Auto Arrange**

[image]

And then move the icons to the right hand side, various programs (e.g. **[DesktopOK](http://www.softwareok.com/?seite=freeware/desktopok)**) allow you to save and restore the desktop icon layout.

Another interesting option you may consider would be Stardock **[Fences](http://www.stardock.com/products/fences/)**.

Comment: I would also recommend fences for what you're trying to accomplish.  Not exactly what you're looking for, but relatively close

Comment: I was about to mention Fences too, but my personal answering machine beat me to it :)